# Debian 9 doesn't detect monitor in hdmi port

Tags: debian, hdmi

I recently installed Debian 9.  It's all ok, the only problem that it's not detecting my monitor in hdmi port.  I'm using a Dell Inspiron 15 Gaming Notebook.

```
xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192                                                                
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm                                       
   1920x1080     60.05*+  59.93    48.04                                                                                             
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88                                                                                                      
   1600x1024     60.17                                                                                                               
   [....]                                                                                             
   512x384       60.00                                                                                                               
   400x300       60.32    56.34                                                                                                      
   320x240       60.05                                                                                                               
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                                                         
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

And `lspci -nn | grep VGA` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:591b] (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1c8c] (rev a1)
```

It works fine in Windows.
My debian: Linux debian 4.9.0-4-amd64 and KDE Plasma.

**Edit1:**
`xrandr --listproviders` ouput:

```
Providers: number : 1
Provider 0: id: 0x45 cap: 0xf, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload, Sink Offload crtcs: 3 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
```

**Edit2:**
[Log Xorg Error](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26524471/)
[Warning when installing Nvidia Driver](https://pasteboard.co/H6eM5pv.jpg)
[OpenGL error](https://pasteboard.co/H6eMvf7.jpg)

**Edit3:**
`update-glx --list glx` output:

```
/usr/lib/mesa-diverted
/usr/lib/nvidia
/usr/lib/nvidia/bumblebee
```

**Edit4:**
[Xorg.0.log without nvidia-xconfig](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26534742/)
[Xorg.0.log with nvidia-xconfig](https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/26534939/)

Answer (score 7):

You have a laptop with two GPUs: in NVidia terminology, this is known as *Optimus Technology*. The complication with that is, it is possible that some physical outputs are wired to a specific GPU only, and it may or may not be possible to switch them.

The outputs you see listed in `xrandr` printout are just what the CPU-integrated Intel GPU is capable of; it is possible that the `DP-1` and/or `HDMI-1` outputs from that GPU are left unconnected, and the external outputs are wired to the NVidia GPU instead.

This problem could be solved by configuring one of the GPUs to pass the rendered output into the other one, effectively using the secondary GPU as a sort of "expansion unit" that provides extra interfaces.

If you are using the open-source `nouveau` driver for the NVidia GPU, it has all the facilities for dealing with this situation any way you choose. You could then use the Intel GPU as a primary and NVidia as a secondary, with a single command like `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0`. That would allow you to completely disable the NVidia GPU when you are not using it, minimizing power consumption.

But if you are using the proprietary `nvidia` driver (`nvidia-current` in Debian packaging), the problem is that the proprietary driver currently has the facilities to act as in primary role only. So to get graphics to the laptop's integrated display, you would need to always have both GPUs up and running.

Please run `xrandr --listproviders` and edit the output into your question; that will tell whether or not the NVidia GPU is currently recognized and which options it has available regarding passing output from one GPU to another.

If the `xrandr --listproviders` indicates the NVidia GPU has the `Sink Output` capability, run `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource <NVidia's number> <Intel's number>` and then run `xrandr` without parameters again; now you should see the outputs available in the Intel GPU too. But in this configuration, you would be using the NVidia GPU as just a "dumb pass-through device", which may be silly given that it's the more powerful of your two GPUs.

Comment: As xrandr --listproviders just showed one output, then i didn't inserted xrandr --setprovideroutputsource <NVidia's number> <Intel's number>.

As for the driver, i'm using what has come with Debian 9, so i guess it's the nouveau.

Comment: Okay. So whichever driver you're using, it is not recognizing the NVidia GPU at all. According to the PCI IDs, it is a GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile, so it's probably too new for `nouveau` as it exists in Debian's current kernel. You'll need `nvidia-current` package from Debian's non-free repository.

Comment: No, not `nvidia-current` which provides an old driver (340) intended only for legacy hardware. Installing it will break the system. Version that support a GTX1050 are 375, 384, 387 or 390.

Comment: And *you would need to always have both GPUs up and running* is wrong (and all outputs are for both cards, this isn't a desktop). The Nvidia driver does NOT enable both cards. It does provide a GUI tool - Nvidia X Server Settings - where, among many other settings, there's a profile selector to enable one or the other (reboot required). Perhaps you should have a better understanding of Nvidia graphics, Nvidia drivers and "Optimus" before answering.

Comment: Oops, you're right. The new metapackage is `nvidia-driver`, which will then pull in a number of things, including `nvidia-kernel-dkms` and `xserver-xorg-video-nvidia`.

Comment: But you're right: the *need to always have both GPUs up and running* needs a qualifier "if you want to switch freely between displays without restarting the X server and your hardware is a *muxless Optimus*". In a *muxless Optimus* hardware, all outputs are *not* available for both cards - that is the main challenge with that setup!

Comment: So, we gonna step in another problem.  Before, i tried to install nvidia drivers in four different ways, and the same problems appeared.

I have tried install from debian wikia tutorial through "apt install linux-headers-$(uname -r|sed 's/[^-]*-[^-]*-//') nvidia-driver".  The gui stopped start, accusing couldn't load OpenGL.  Then i installed nvidia-xconfig, another error popped, i can post it the log above. I did it a apt purge 'nvidia-*'.

Downloading from Nvidia site, the same error appeared, but i couldn't reverse.
I tried other 2 ways, same errors. Updated the question with the logs.

Comment: The problem is probably that you now have the non-free OpenGL libraries (which can only be used with the non-free `nvidia` driver) and the free `nouveau` driver is still loaded. You may have to ensure that the `nouveau` kernel module is blacklisted, run `update-initramfs -u` and then reboot. With that setup, you might initially get a GUI on the HDMI-connected monitor only, until you can run `xrandr --setprovideroutputsource` the opposite way to make NVidia GPU use the Intel one as an "extender". But when the `nvidia` driver is at all functional, I'd want to see which connectors it can see.

Comment: The `libglvnd` library is supposed to act as a switcher between the non-free OpenGL implementation (for the `nvidia` driver) and the free Mesa OpenGL (for the Intel GPU and the `nouveau` driver). But your attempting multiple installation methods may have confused things: it's supposed to work so that regular clients only see the `libglvnd` libs and those will then access the real OpenGL libraries appropriate to whichever GPU is in use.

Comment: I reinstalled the Debian.  Created the file /etc/modprobe.d/backlist.conf, blacklisting the nouveau driver.  File will be above.  Ran update-initramfs -u.  Rebooted, installed nvidia-driver in recovery mode, so no GUI and no message about nouveau module conflict, but the error persists.  When i start the GUI, by startx, accuses OpenGL error.

Comment: Looks like the X server is preferring the first GPU it finds, then. If you run `update-glx --list glx` there should now be at least two GLX implementations. Run `update-glx --config glx` and select the "mesa-diverted" option to hopefully get rid of the OpenGL errors for now. The next step would be seeing if the `nvidia` driver can now see the second GPU and, hopefully, any displays connected to it.

Comment: I'll post the output of update-glx above.
It worked as you said, now it's now not showing the error of OpenGL.  But continue not showing the hdmi monitor and the `xrandr --listproviders` is showing just one provider, as before.

Comment: Does `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` show anything about the `nvidia` driver? Any error messages about it?

Comment: As i posted above, seems like it still loading the nouveau driver. In line 60 until line 71, and in line 95.
So i installed `nvidia-xconfig` e changed in to `update-glx --config glx`.  Then the errors that output it's No devices found and No screens found, as posted in the log.