# Debian 9 with Mate does not discover the second monitor

Tags: debian, nvidia, xrandr, intel, hdmi

I have a laptop with devices

```
    inxi -Fi
System:    Host: Precision Kernel: 4.9.0-8-amd64 x86_64 (64 bit) Desktop: MATE 1.16.2
           Distro: Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)
Machine:   Device: laptop System: Dell product: Precision M4800 v: 00
           Mobo: Dell model: 0V5GVY v: A00 UEFI: Dell v: A15 date: 09/29/2015
Battery    BAT0: charge: 90.0 Wh 187.0% condition: 48.1/90.0 Wh (53%)
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i7-4810MQ (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB 
           clock speeds: max: 3800 MHz 1: 2778 MHz 2: 2800 MHz 3: 2799 MHz 4: 2800 MHz 5: 2800 MHz 6: 2796 MHz
           7: 2799 MHz 8: 2788 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
           Card-2: NVIDIA GK107GLM [Quadro K1100M]
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.2 drivers: modesetting,nouveau (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.02hz
           GLX Renderer: N/A GLX Version: N/A
Audio:     Card-1 Intel 8 Series/C220 Series High Definition Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Card-2 Intel Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller driver: snd_hda_intel
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.9.0-8-amd64
Network:   Card-1: Intel Ethernet Connection I217-LM driver: e1000e
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: 34:e6:d7:42:6d:0a
           Card-2: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter driver: wl
           IF: wlp3s0 state: up mac: ac:b5:7d:6c:5d:51
           WAN IP: 85.219.180.128 IF: veth71e62fc@if11 ip-v4: N/A
           IF: wlp3s0 ip-v4: 192.168.0.100 IF: veth0f7439f@if15 ip-v4: N/A IF: vethd545b43@if13 ip-v4: N/A
           IF: vethfbbf8c3@if5 ip-v4: N/A IF: eno1 ip-v4: N/A IF: veth648cee2@if9 ip-v4: N/A
           IF: docker0 ip-v4: 172.17.0.1 IF: vethc02ae83@if7 ip-v4: N/A
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 240.1GB (15.1% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ADATA_SP550 size: 240.1GB
Partition: ID-1: / size: 46G used: 17G (39%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
           ID-2: /home size: 165G used: 8.3G (6%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda4
           ID-3: swap-1 size: 10.00GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda3
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 48.0C mobo: N/A gpu: 38.0
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 255 Uptime: 1 min Memory: 1297.3/15956.2MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.3.5
```

**A want to share my screen with second monitor**, but after connected HDMI nothing happend. Second monitor is just not detected. I tried execute command

```
xrandr --listproviders
Providers: number : 2
Provider 0: id: 0x8d cap: 0x2, Sink Output crtcs: 3 outputs: 4 associated providers: 0 name:modesetting
Provider 1: id: 0x66 cap: 0x7, Source Output, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 0 name:nouveau
rafal@Precision:~$ xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0 
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  35 (RRSetProviderOutputSource)
  Value in failed request:  0x8d
  Serial number of failed request:  16
  Current serial number in output stream:  17
```

And I get error.I remmeber that once below command works, and after connected HDMI I just saw second monitor and I can turn on it.

> xrandr --setprovideroutputsource 1 0

What happend now in my system I' dont know. I supposed some package may be updated or upgraded, and this caused that today my second monitor dosen't detected. Then a give help from this subject
[Debian 9 doesn't detect monitor in hdmi port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421939/debian-9-doesnt-detect-monitor-in-hdmi-port)
but not today

I tried also create file `xorg.conf` with content

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "Intel"
    Driver "intel"
#   Option "AccelMethod" "uxa"
#   Option "VSync" "false"
EndSection
```

Only what I got that was white screen on my HDMI monitor, but this was only once.

**EDIT 1:**

```
 xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  59.93    47.99  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   960x600       60.00  
   960x540       59.99  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   576x432       60.06  
   512x384       60.00  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   320x240       60.05  
VGA-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: `xrandr --listproviders` lists the availables graphic cards. Please, provide the output of `xrandr` with no options.

Comment: I added result command below EDIT 1. Thank for interesting my problem, I want to noticed actual HDMI is connected to PC

Comment: Are you sure that the HDMI ports is functionnal on your laptop ? Did you already see it working ? Have you a way to connect it with VGA instead of HDMI ?

Comment: I just tested HDMI on my TV. This same result nothing happend, but when I connected VGA to TV works, a I saw image form my laptop. So my HDMI port is damaged ? Exist some way in linux to tested this port to confirm this, I can't believe it that can just stop works.

Comment: Looks like an hardware problem, yes. Maybe you can try booting a Ubuntu Live CD  with the external monitor plugged in while booting.

Comment: It is possible also run form USB this same way ?

Comment: Yes, no matter the medium used to boot. The idea is to try with a more "user friendly" Linux distro which is supposed to make the work by itself.